# deploy npx create-react-app my-app in the server apache-http-server

Tags: reactjs

I created react app using the "npx create-react-app". It's working fine. Here in thins case i used "npm start" to run my 'reactApplication'. But want to move it to "Apache HTTP" server,so I did run the command "npm run build", that generated some "build" folder. Up to here it's ok. But when I copied the "build" folder to the "ApacheHTTP" I'm not getting any output.

Comment: What are the files under the "build" folder? Can you please list it on the question?

Comment: Are permissions correct? What's the output, is it outputting HTML? Right click => View Source. Do you see html? Do you see it trying to load your bundle.js file? Check the network tab, and refresh the page. Do the resources exist? Are you getting any console error messages?

Comment: manifest.json
asset-manifest.json
precache-manifest.7f00308af35197f8f0b4d3b4d44f6855.js
service-worker.js
index.html
static--folder
inside static folder -- js folder(having related js files)
inside static folder -- css folder(having related css files)
++++++++++++
Thank you varit and franker. Now I just inspected browser. So I found serveral 404 errors. Ex: in index.html, initially in my "build" folder I'm having "href="/manifest.json"" so I replaced with "href="/build/manifest.json" like that I did for all 'src' and 'href' it's worked fine. Because in my server other apps existed.

Comment: Do I need to write 'appname' in front of the 'href' and 'src' everytime